# Get File folder path in MVC view page

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, plugins

I need to open file dialog box and Get Folder/directory path from my view page and get that path on controller e.g. if I browse folder Inputfiles I should get path as - C:\user\XYZ\Desktop\Inputfiles

Comment: Okay... And what have you done so far in order to solve it first by yourself?

Comment: You cannot. It would be a major security breach if your server could discover the file structure of a users computer. A file input will send only the file name, not the path